# Возможно ли воспользоваться ИК датчиком блока FaceID

Tags: ios, swift, apple, sdk

Возможно ли явным образом с помощью **IOS SDK (Swift)** получить доступ к ИК камере блока **FaceID iPhone**, например чтобы получить инфракрасное изображение, или у нас есть возможность использовать только общий блок **FaceID** без взаимодействия с отдельными элементами этой системы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, датчиком пользоваться нельзя.

Можно только пользоваться фреймворком Local Authentication для защиты контента в приложении с помощью FaceID. При этом используется стандартный системный UI без возможности изменения.

Comment: Что, совсем никак? В интернете, в английском сегменте, есть вроде понятия «если не системными вызовами, не официальным апи» и т.д. Не добраться до датчика никак даже в обход?

Comment: Да, никак, даже "системными вызовами, неофициальными API". Может быть только с помощью jailbreak, но скорее всего на сенсоре аппаратная защита и не получится даже так.